# Writing a function for arranging the elements in an array

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, function

The aim is to arrange the elements of an array from positive on the left side and negative on the right side. The constraint is that only one array is to be used. Also, the order of occurrence of elements should remain the same in the arranged output array . 
Sample Input

10(no. of elements in array)
-6 7 13 10 -8 15 5 -9 2 -1(array elements)
Sample Output

7 
13 
10 
15 
5 
2 
-6 
-8 
-9 
-1

Comment: [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) is made for exactly this situation.

Comment: Since you are new here, you should take a look at this: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: @user3386109: this is not a stable sort but a stable partition. And why should the programming language matter ?

Comment: Use Quick Sort (Lookup the algorithm), it uses only one array.

Comment: @Rhnbmpl Quicksort is not stable. And although you could modify Quicksort to make it stable, that's overkill. The problem is to *partition* the array, not *sort* it. Partitioning is an O(n) operation. Sorting is O(n log n).

Comment: i am new in programming. so i'm familiar with c. kindly tell accordingly.

Comment: i added the sample input and output case for the question. Please check accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to *partition* the elements of the array in a *stable* way. As already suggested in a comment, you can use the [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) function template:

```
template<class BidirIt, class UnaryPredicate>
BidirIt stable_partition(BidirIt first, BidirIt last, UnaryPredicate p);
```

> Reorders the elements in the range `[first, last)` in such a way that
>   all elements for which the predicate `p` returns `true` precede the
>   elements for which predicate `p` returns `false`. Relative order of the
>   elements is preserved.

As an example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

auto main() -> int {
   std::vector<int> v{0, -1, -7, 3, 5, -9, 2};

   // predicate for partitioning
   auto pred = [](int x) {
      return x >= 0;
   };

   std::stable_partition(v.begin(), v.end(), pred);

   for (auto i: v)
      std::cout << i << ' ';
   std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The output is:

```
0 3 5 2 -1 -7 -9
```

The predicate `pred` returns `true` for the elements that belong to the first group (i.e., non-negative elements) and `false` for the elements that belong to the second one, (i.e., negative elements).

Note that both `std::stable_partition` and `std::partition` return an iterator to the first element of the second group, in case you want to know the group boundaries.